# ERROR: function to_timestamp(character varying) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I have time column (string) which looks like this:

```
time
1645437571.1399999
1645437571.14
1645437571.1455667
1645437571.2
1645437572
1645738427
1645738427
```

When I do:

```
select to_timestamp(1645437571.1399999);
```

individually for each value in that column I always get proper response, something like:

```
2022-02-21 09:59:31.140000 +00:00
```

But when I do:

```
select to_timestamp(time) from pmu;
```

I get error:

> [42883] ERROR: function to_timestamp(character varying) does not exist
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might
> need to add explicit type casts. Position: 8

I understand it's because characters are varying so if I define some format like this:

```
select to_timestamp(time, 'DD-MM-YYYY SS:MS:US') from pmu;
```

Than I get:

> [22008] ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "1645437571.14"
> It should also work for empty values.

Comment: The best solution would be to `ALTER` the table and change that column to `timestamp` rather than the dreaded unix epoch disguised as a string.

Answer (score 5):

to_timestamp(varchar) does not exist. You have to cast your data before using to_timestamp

```
select to_timestamp(time::numeric) from pmu;
```

Comment: And what should I use in case I have empty values, I've edited my questions since I forgot to add that as my case.

Comment: @Hrvoje: What is your definition of an empty value? NULL or a varchar with length 0 ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant NULL - nothing in field.

Comment: if the value is null to_timestamp returns null [Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m8RwskabwsiwAA7EjEQ1As/0)